# Родственность слов, однокоренные слова

Tags: однокоренные-слова, лексикография

В каком отечественном словаре можно узнать, что перечисленные ниже русские слова являются однокоренными:
**град, город, городить, ограда, огранка, градус, градиент, градарь**?

Comment: Ни в каком. Градус и градиент заимствования, а в таких случаях, даже если есть общий морф в языке-источнике (или в общем языке-предке), не принято считать слова однокоренными.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

Родственность слов можно обнаружить по разным словарям: толковым(узнать значение и сравнить), словарям строения слов(морфемным), словообразовательным(проследить, от какого слова), иногда помогает и этимологический(выяснить,из какого языка заимствовано и не является ли корень просто похожим по звучанию)Только не стоит пользоваться онлайн-словарями однокоренных слов,там много ошибок, потому что слова выбираются автоматически роботом.

Град(в значении город), город, городить,ограда, градарь(огородник)- исторически однокоренные. Здесь варианты корня город//град. Если нужно отобрать слова , однокоренные на данный момент, список уменьшится, потому что значения слов поменялись и теперь город - не то, что огорожено.

огранка - от грань(край), граница, гранить

градус, градиент - заимствования из латыни, совсем разные корни

Comment: Ограда и градус, стало быть, разнокоренные. И откуда тогда пошли эти совершенно разные слова? Какие у них источники?